# Access to us.archive.ubuntu.com has been blocked after testing uplift script

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, updates

I was testing an uplift script that installs dependencies to uplift Bionic to use libvirt-7.9.0. This test cycle consisted of running apt install on a bunch of packages, checking the results, then apt removing all these packages to start again.

After about 20min of this cycle, the apt install is suddenly failing because access to us.archive.ubuntu.com is refused. On one machine I can't even get to the actual ip address.

The exact error is:
Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

Is there a rate limit for accessing the packages? And if so, what is actually blocking further access, and will it resolve itself over time?

Comment: You've got a DNS problem on the affected machine, not a ratelimit.  There are no ratelimits on the repository servers.  You need to solve the underlying DNS/networking problem on the machine directly so it can resolve the domains.

Comment: @ThomasWard it appears that the network interfaces are gone. Any hypothesis what can cause the network interface to disappear when running apt update/upgrade/install?

Comment: drivers for virtual interfaces going awol in the guest, possibly.  But normally this would be a case of you misconfiguring the Guest VM, or the libvirt/KVM interfaces being removed from the VM.  You might want to just restart and rebuild your VM.

Comment: @ThomasWard your advice is sound: after an hour trying to RCA the loss of the network interfaces, it is more productive to mark it up to a fluke and start from scratch. Thank you for your time.